# Javascript, prototype not inheriting

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm starting to use prototypes in Javascript with the help of the Mozilla Developer Network.

My problem is that I have 2 types: `Field`, and `TextField`, which inherits `Field`.
I want to create an Object from `TextField` and call an inherited method `writeForm`. Here's the code :

```
/**
 * abstract type .
 * Sets a parameter of the funcard associated with the html field. name => value
 */
function Field(){
    console.log('create Field');
    this.name = null;
    this.value = null;
};
Field.prototype = {
    /**
     * Write the html Field in the field of the same name .
     * This function must be overridden in each new type of Field.
     */
    writeForm: function(){
        // Function overloading
        console.log('writeForm');
    }
};


/**
 * type text input
 */
function TextField(){
    Field.call(this);
    console.log('create TextField');
};
TextField.prototype = Object.create(Field.prototype, {
    //Override
    writeForm: function(){
        Field.prototype.writeForm.apply(this, arguments);
        // Function overloading
        console.log('writeForm TextField');
    }
});



var myfield = Object.create(TextField);
myfield.writeForm();
```

But the last line gives me an **Uncaught TypeError: myfield.writeForm is not a function**. I don't really understand why it can't find my method.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You want `Object.create(TextField.prototype)` or `new TextField` since you're using a constructor.

Comment: `var myfield = new TextField();`

Answer (score 2):

First off, you're going to want to instantiate instances of `TextField` using either of these:

```
Object.create(TextField.prototype);
new TextField();
```

I'd suggest using `new TextField()` since you've defined a constructor.

Next, the [second parameter to `Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Using_propertiesObject_argument_with_Object.create()) takes a set of property descriptors, which are different from just assigning properties directly to an object. To get an idea of how property descriptors work, check out [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties). Instead, you'll want to assign your functions directly to the prototype after creating an instance of `Field.prototype`.

```
TextField.prototype = Object.create(Field.prototype);
TextField.prototype.writeForm = function() {
  Field.prototype.writeForm.apply(this, arguments);
  // Fonction à surcharger
  console.log('writeForm TextField');
};
```

Comment: Oh so, I will do `TextField.prototype.myFunction= function(){/*...*/}` for each method of my prototypes, that's right ?

It seems to work :)
Thanks !

Comment: @Thaledric You got it :)